# Using an algorithm in matlab:Determine the displacements u_{i} of the joints

Tags: matlab

[image]

The displacement formulation for a plane truss is similar to that of a mass–spring system. The differences are
(1) the stiffnesses of the members are k_{i} = (EA/L)_{i},
where E is the modulus of elasticity, A represents the cross-sectional area, and
L is the length of the member;
(2) there are two components of displacement ateach joint. For the statically indeterminate truss shown, the displacement formulation yields the symmetric equations Ku = p, where

[image]

Determine the displacements u_{i} of the joints

Using an algorithm in matlab

Could someone help me with the algorithm?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the backslash operator. Type `help slash` for more information. Basically,

```
u = K\p
```

means `u = inv(K)*p` but is a faster more accurate way to do it. 
I haven't tested it for your problem, but this is generally how to go about these sorts of problems.